# resetting the parameters of a for loop from inside the loop in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am working through the project euler problems in Python 3 as a fun way to learn the language, and my solution to problem number three I feel is a little funky. The problem is to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143, and I solved it in a pretty sprawling way as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# encoding: utf-8
# what is the largest prime factor of whatever the user types


def main():
    original = int(input("Input a number: "))
    if original == isPrime(original):
        print(original, "is prime")
    else:
        print(factor(original), "is the largest prime factor of", original)

def factor(number):
    nummy=2
    for num in range(nummy, number):
        if (number%num==0 and isPrime(num)==num):
            biggest=int(num)
            number=int(number/biggest)
            nummy = int(biggest+2)
            print("so far,",biggest, "is the biggest prime factor...")
            if number < biggest:
                break
    return biggest      

def isPrime(value):
    for num in range(2, int(value**0.5)+1):
        if value%num==0:
            return int(value/num)
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

as you can see, in my "factor" function, I tried to update the upper limit of the range in my for loop, but it didn't really work like I was expecting so I had to add the if number < biggest block to get the whole thing to run in a reasonable amount of time.

Is there a way to update the parameters of a for loop from inside the loop?

I appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: You can't tweak range.  Here's a hint.  Use a `while` statement instead of `for...range...`.

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a go and post the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(nummy, number)` is evaluated before you enter the `for` loop so it is not possible in your case.

Generally it is possible in python(though not always), but it is a bad idea. It is better to check for changed conditions and break out of the loop as you did.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will run in reasonable time.

I'll point out a few things, without giving out solutions:

You don't need to try and divide X with every number up to X to know it's prime. If it's not divisible by 2, it won't be divisible by 4 either; if not by 3, less so by 9. You can also stop earlier than (X-1) -- after all, X won't be divisible by a prime larger than... what?

Well, I had 3 more items, but they all derive from the above. Hope it helps you!

Comment: thanks very much. for the number in the euler project question, this runs pretty fast, but if i feed it a big prime or just any really giant number, it just grinds away seemingly forever. I'll try and speed 'er up some!

Answer (score 1):

As S. Lott said, you will want to use a while loop, but you would want to assign the ceiling of the range to a variable since you want it to be mutable.

Also, I am not sure why you are doing:

```
biggest=int(num)
number=int(number/biggest)
nummy = int(biggest+2)
```

num would already be an int (otherwise, you would not be able to do the mathematical operations to do prior to that point). Integer division could also be done as:

```
number = number // biggest
```